# Why hashcode calling twice?

Tags: java

```
 public class A {

@Override
        public int hashCode(){
        System.out.println("hashcode");
        return 1;
        }
        public static void main(String... s){
        HashMap<A,String> hm = new HashMap<A,String>();
        A A1 = new A();
        A A2 = A1;
        A A3 =new A();
        hm.put(A2,"sometext");
        hm.put(A3,"sometext2");
        System.out.println(hm);
        }



}
```

While run the above code "hascode" is printing twice, May anyone please explain the reason?

OUTPUT:
hashcode
hashcode
hashcode
hashcode
{com.svdo.td3e.launcher.dao.A@1=sometext2, com.svdo.td3e.launcher.dao.A@1=sometext}

Comment: You have a typo in the `hashcode()` method name. It has to be `hashCode()` otherwise it doesn't override the `Object#hashCode()` method.

Comment: I just tested this and it isn't printing anything. Also giving me a warning on the second `HashMap<A, String>` : `redundant type arguments in new expression (use diamond operator instead)`

Comment: What version of Java is this? Testing and look at looking at Java SE 6 it is careful to call `hashCode()` only once in put. It also stores the hash-code in the map entry so doesn't recall when resolving table collisions.

Answer (score 1):

In your code, `hashcode` won't be called at all because it doesn't override `hashCode` (with an upper case `c`).

If you rectify the name of the method, it will be called an undefined number of times that depends on the details of the `HashMap` implementation. In my case it is only called once with JDK 8.

If you want to understand why it is called twice in your case, I suggest using a debugger and stepping into the `put` method to see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

Above code won't print any things, because you are not invoking custom "hashcode()" method in your code. Don't assume you are overriding Object hashCode() method.Check method name available in Object class.

Answer (score 0):

i Got it, one extra "hashcode" is printing due to toString method.